# WAP in C or java: Consider two char arrays, "abcdefg" and "xyz"...the output must print "axbyczdefg"

Tags: c, logic

Consider two char arrays, "abcdefg" and "xyz".

The output must print "axbyczdefg", please help I've been stuck on this since morning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main() {
    int i,j;
    char a[]="abcdefg";
    char b[]="xyz";
    for(i=0;i<=6;i++) {
        printf("%c",a[i]);
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++) {
             printf("%c",b[j]);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Answer to this question in C language will be more preferable.

Comment: Please read how to ask, show some code... something 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: *what have you tried?* provide some **code** or anything you already have achieved

Comment: If you want answers in C, then why did you add the `java` tag? Please pick one or the other.

Comment: Post what you have tried until now..no one is going to write a code for you

Comment: Since the two arrays are not of same size,hence i'm not able to print correct answer..tbh i can't really think of any possible logic in C,,if possible do help and provide an answer Lino,thank u

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{ int i,j;
 char a[]="pqrstuv";
 char b[]="cdef";
 

 for(i=0;i<=6;i++)
 {
  printf("%c",a[i]);
  for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
  {
   
   printf("%c",b[j]);
  }
 }

 
}

Comment: "WAP" - now that's new to me :D

Comment: will do,tbh i'm new here

Comment: Edit your question..don't post your code in comments

Comment: Anyone got the logic yet?

Comment: Can anyone provide me the answer..?TBH i just made an account here and hoping someone can solve it as it was asked to one of my friend,i could not find the answer anywhere else

Comment: "WAP" is for "want a program" ?

Comment: WAP means Write a Program

Comment: Yunnosch can u please help me on this

Comment: "Write A Program" as in "for free", is off-topic here. Check the coment by @Someprogrammerdude on useful things to read.

Comment: Any help or hint will be really appriciated

Comment: Can you at least provide a hint to solve this,,for lets say helping someone as a human?doing some good deed? moreover it will brush up your knowledge aswell

Comment: Here's an algorithm: In *one* loop (not nested) print the first character of `a` followed by the first character of `b`. In the next iteration print the second character of each array. And so on. If beyond the end of either `a` or `b` don't print anything from it. Continue looping until the end of the longest string.

Comment: Ok, I will help. Edit you question to explain more about what you want to achieve. Consider how anybody should know how you want to derive the desired output from input. Shall we guess? Otherwise the anser is `printf("axbyczdefg"\n");` You need to explain what you tried, the posted code is quite far from anything which could achieve close to the goal. Explain your thinking, explain your obstacles. Show the output you get. Explain what is wrong about it. And please stop writing comments which are basically "WAP" again and again.

Comment: Some Programmer dude...thank u so much...will try to implement using the help u provided.

Comment: Yunnosch ..ok sir,i'll try to edit..as i'm new here i really dont know how stackoverflow works but anyway thank u

Comment: Again, please read the list of useful informaiton provided by Someprogrammerdude.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{ int i,j;
 char a[]="pqrstuv";
 char b[]="cdef";
 

 for(i=0;i<=6;i++)
 {
  printf("%c",a[i]);
  if(i<4)
  {
  printf("%c",b[i]); 
  }
 }

 
}

Comment: this is the answer finally.

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *a = "abcdefg";
    const char *b = "xyz";

    while(*a || *b){
        if(*a)
            putchar(*a++);
        if(*b)
            putchar(*b++);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
@Test
public void test() {
    List<String> strings1 = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g");
    List<String> strings2 = Arrays.asList("x", "y", "z");

    List<String> result = join(strings1, strings2);
    System.out.println(String.join(" ", result));
}

List<String> join(List<String> first, List<String> second) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < first.size(); i++) {
       result.add(first.get(i));

       if (i < second.size()) {
           result.add(second.get(i));
       }
    }

    if ( second.size() > first.size() ) {
        result.addAll(second.subList(first.size(), second.size()));
    }

    return result;
}
```